# Не могу изменить аннотацию для параметра метода

Tags: java, рефлексия, аннотации

Всем привет.
Есть аннотация над параметром метода, я хотел бы изменить ее значение. Т.е. задать новую аннотацию.

В Executable, который наследует Method есть поле Parameter[]. Я получаю его, после чего беру карту declaredAnnotations. Кладу туда новую аннотацию, но далее она не проростает.

Если вызвать Method.getParameterAnnotations(), то вернется массив со старыми значениями.

Думаю, пробелема в том, что аннотации параметров хранятся не только в виде карты объекта Parameter, но и в виде массива байт parameterAnnotations в Method.

И именно Method.getParameterAnnotations дергается кодом выше.

Как сгенерить корректный parameterAnnotations я не знаю. Там хранится массив байт, а далее парсится.

Вопрос такой: Как изменить значение аннотации под параметром метода?

Comment: Этот вопрос в данный момент включает несколько вопросов. Его следует переформулировать, чтобы он был сфокусирован только на одной проблеме.

Comment: @RomanC, да, вы правы. Переформулировал вопрос.

Comment: Вместо объяснений словами как выгдялит ваш код, приведите сам код.